# GJK algorithm gets stuck in a loop of different Voronoi Region cases

Tags: c++, algorithm, collision-detection

I'm currently trying to implement the simplified GJK algorithm presented in https://mollyrocket.com/849 into my C++ game.

However, I'm experiencing strange behaviour in the second and third dimension: The algorithm sometimes (which is quite often when called multiple times a second) gets stuck in a loop of cases. As an example, the debug messages print the following to std::cout over and over again:

```
3ACxAB
4AB
3ABxAC
4ABD
4AD
```

If you have a look at my code, you'll see that these lines represent the cases the algorithm allows. E.g. *3ACxAB* means that the simplex currently is a triangle and that the origin is in the voronoi region of the face, in direction of the cross product *AC x AB* (which may be interpreted as "above" or "below" the triangle). The case *4AB* means that the simplex is a tetrahedron and the origin is in the voronoi region of the edge *AB*.

*A* always is the newly added point. In the code, *A* always is the greatest index of `simplex`. (^simplex[1]` if it's a line, 2 if a triangle and 3 in the case of a) tetrahedron.

Even after days of searching for mistakes (I found some, but there still is one or more left), the algorithm won't work.

Do you see any problem in the code? Because neither I nor two friends of mine do.

PS: I didn't copy any of the calculations (e.g. cross products for the direction vector) from Casey's video. After watching it, I made up my mind myself, so here potential problems may lie, especially in the third dimension, where Casey intentionally *didn't* speak about.

---

My support function:

```
//hullA/B: convex hull of A resp. B; baseA/B: location of A/B
Vector3f gjkSupport(Vector3f direction,
        std::vector<GLfloat> hullA, std::vector<GLfloat> baseA,
        std::vector<GLfloat> hullB, std::vector<GLfloat> baseB) {
    //Initialize
    GLfloat maxDotP = -std::numeric_limits<GLfloat>::max();
    Vector3f furthestPointA, furthestPointB;
    //Get furthest point in given direction out of hullA by getting the maximum dot
    //product of the direction vector and a hull vertex's position vector
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < hullA.size(); i += 3) {
        Vector3f current (hullA[i]+baseA[0], hullA[i+1]+baseA[1], hullA[i+2]+baseA[2]);
        // * = dot product
        GLfloat dotP = direction * current;
        if (dotP > maxDotP) {
            maxDotP = dotP;
            furthestPointA = current;
        }
    }
    maxDotP = -std::numeric_limits<GLfloat>::max();
    //Get furthest point in negative of the given direction out of hullB
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < hullB.size(); i += 3) {
        Vector3f current (hullB[i]+baseB[0], hullB[i+1]+baseB[1], hullB[i+2]+baseB[2]);
        GLfloat dotP = -direction * current;
        if (dotP > maxDotP) {
            maxDotP = dotP;
            furthestPointB = current;
        }
    }
    //Furthest Minkowski Difference point is difference of d*A[i]-(-d)*B[j]
    return furthestPointA - furthestPointB;
}
```

My simplex function:

```
bool gjkSimplex(std::vector<Vector3f> &simplex, Vector3f &direction) {
    GLuint simplexSize = simplex.size();
    std::cout << simplexSize;
    switch (simplexSize) {
    //If the simplex is a line segment
    case 2:
        //Point is closest feature
        if ((simplex[0]-simplex[1])*-simplex[1] < 0) {
            std::cout << "A";
            simplex = {simplex[1]};
            //direction = A0
            direction = -simplex[1];
        //Line is closest feature
        } else {
            std::cout << "AB";
            //direction = AB x (A0 x AB)
            // ^ = cross product
            direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[1]) ^ ((-simplex[1]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[1]));
        }
        break;
    //If the simplex is a triangle
    case 3:
        //Point is closest feature
        if ((simplex[0]-simplex[2])*(-simplex[2]) < 0 && (simplex[1]-simplex[2])*(-simplex[2]) < 0) {
            std::cout << "A";
            //direction = A0
            direction = -simplex[2];
            simplex = {simplex[1]};
        //Line to second-latest point is closest feature
        } else if ((((simplex[0]-simplex[2])^(simplex[1]-simplex[2]))^(simplex[1]-simplex[2]))*-simplex[2] > 0) {
            std::cout << "AB";
            //direction = AB x (A0 x AB)
            direction = (simplex[1]-simplex[2]) ^ ((-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[2]));
            simplex = {simplex[1], simplex[2]};
        //Line to oldest point is closest feature
        } else if (((simplex[0]-simplex[2])^((simplex[0]-simplex[2])^(simplex[1]-simplex[2])))*-simplex[2] > 0) {
            std::cout << "AC";
            //direction = AC x (A0 x AC)
            direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[2]) ^ ((-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[2]));
            simplex = {simplex[0], simplex[2]};
        //Face is closest feature
        } else {
            //Origin is in direction AC x AB
            if (((simplex[1]-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[2])) * (-simplex[2]) < 0) {
                std::cout << "ACxAB";
                //direction = AC x AB
                direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[2]);
            //origin is in direction AB x AC (other side of the face)
            } else {
                std::cout << "ABxAC";
                //direction = AB x AC
                direction = (simplex[1]-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[2]);
                simplex = {simplex[1], simplex[0], simplex[2]};
            }
        }
        break;
    //If the simplex is a tetrahedron
    case 4:
        //Newest point is closest feature
        if ((simplex[0]-simplex[3])*(-simplex[3]) < 0 && (simplex[1]-simplex[3])*(-simplex[3]) < 0 &&
                (simplex[2]-simplex[3])*(-simplex[3]) < 0) {
            std::cout << "A";
            //direction = A0
            direction = -simplex[3];
            simplex = {simplex[3]};
        //Edge between newest and second-newest point is closest feature
        } else if ((((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ ((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]))) * (-simplex[2]) < 0) &&
                ((((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[2]) < 0)) {
            std::cout << "AB";
            //direction = AB x (A0 x AB)
            direction = (simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ ((-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]));
            simplex = {simplex[2], simplex[3]};
        //Edge between newest and third-newest vertex is closest feature
        } else if ((((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ ((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3]))) * (-simplex[2]) < 0) &&
                ((((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[2]) < 0)) {
            std::cout << "AC";
            //direction = AC x (A0 x AC)
            direction = (simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ ((-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3]));
            simplex = {simplex[1], simplex[3]};
        //Edge between newest and oldest point is closest feature
        } else if ((((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ ((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3]))) * (-simplex[2]) < 0) &&
                ((((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[2]) < 0)) {
            std::cout << "AD";
            //direction = AD x (A0 x AD)
            direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ ((-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3]));
            simplex = {simplex[0], simplex[3]};
        //Face between the three newest points is closest feature
        } else if (((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) > 0) {
            std::cout << "ABC";
            //direction = AC x AB (outer normal of face)
            direction = (simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]);
            simplex = {simplex[1], simplex[3], simplex[2]};
        //Face between newest, second-newest and oldest point is closest feature
        } else if (((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) > 0) {
            std::cout << "ABD";
            //direction = AB x AD
            direction = (simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3]);
            simplex = {simplex[0], simplex[2], simplex[3]};
        //Face between newest, second-oldest and oldest point is closest feature
        } else if (((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) > 0) {
            std::cout << "ACD";
            //direction = AD x AC
            direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3]);
            simplex = {simplex[0], simplex[3], simplex[1]};
        //Origin is encased by simplex
        } else {
            //Collision detected
            std::cout << "ABCD";
            return true;
        }
        break;
    default:
        direction = {1,1,1};
        simplex = {};
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return false;
};
```

GJK main loop:

```
//Narrow Phase collision function using GJK
bool SolidObject::collidesWith(SolidObject *object) {
    //Initialize by using an arbitrary direction
    Vector3f direction (1,1,1);
    std::vector<Vector3f> simplex;
    Vector3f point = gjkSupport(direction,
            this->meshes[0].getConvexHull(), this->base, object->meshes[0].getConvexHull(), object->base);
    simplex = {point};
    //Set direction to the negative of the resulting point
    direction = -point;

    bool originInSimplex = false;
    while (!originInSimplex) {
        //Get furthest point in new direction
        point = gjkSupport(direction,
                this->meshes[0].getConvexHull(), this->base, object->meshes[0].getConvexHull(), object->base);
        //The furthest point in the negative direction is not in the opposing octant
        //  => no collision
        if (point*direction < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        //Add point to the simplex
        simplex.push_back(point);
        //Update simplex and direction, and return whether the simplex contains the origin
        originInSimplex = gjkSimplex(simplex, direction);
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete program exhibiting the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the triangle case:**

```
//Point is closest feature
if ((simplex[0]-simplex[2])*(-simplex[2]) < 0 && (simplex[1]-simplex[2])*(-simplex[2]) < 0) {
    std::cout << "A";
    //direction = A0
    direction = -simplex[2];
    simplex = {simplex[1]};
}
```

It should be

```
simplex = {simplex[2]};
```

**In the tetrahedron case:**

All your edge checks perform the dot prodocut with`simplex[2]`, but they should use the latest point `simplex[3]`.

I think your first edge check uses the wrong face for the second condition, so instead of

```
if ((((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ ((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]))) * (-simplex[2]) < 0) &&
        ((((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[2]) < 0)) {
    std::cout << "AB";
    //direction = AB x (A0 x AB)
    direction = (simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ ((-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]));
    simplex = {simplex[2], simplex[3]};
}
```

it should be

```
if ((((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ ((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]))) * (-simplex[3]) < 0) &&
        ((((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) < 0)) {
    std::cout << "AB";
    //direction = AB x (A0 x AB)
    direction = (simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ ((-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]));
    simplex = {simplex[2], simplex[3]};
}
```

the same holds true for the second condition of the second edge check, where it should be:

```
((((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) < 0)
```

and the second condition of the third edge check:

```
((((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) < 0)
```

I also fixed the output simplexe of the triangle checks. The last point of the input simplex should be always the last point of the output simplex. Also, the ordering of the points should be consistent and match the calculated direction.

Here is the complete fixed function:

```
bool gjkSimplex(std::vector<Vector3f> &simplex, Vector3f &direction) {
    GLuint simplexSize = simplex.size();
    std::cout << simplexSize;
    switch (simplexSize) {
    //If the simplex is a line segment
    case 2:
        //Point is closest feature
        if ((simplex[0]-simplex[1])*-simplex[1] < 0) {
            std::cout << "A";
            //direction = A0
            direction = -simplex[1];
            simplex = {simplex[1]};
        //Line is closest feature
        } else {
            std::cout << "AB";
            //direction = AB x (A0 x AB)
            // ^ = cross product
            direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[1]) ^ ((-simplex[1]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[1]));
        }
        break;
    //If the simplex is a triangle
    case 3:
        //Point is closest feature
        if ((simplex[0]-simplex[2])*(-simplex[2]) < 0 && (simplex[1]-simplex[2])*(-simplex[2]) < 0) {
            std::cout << "A";
            //direction = A0
            direction = -simplex[2];
            simplex = {simplex[2]};
        //Line to second-latest point is closest feature
        } else if ((((simplex[0]-simplex[2])^(simplex[1]-simplex[2]))^(simplex[1]-simplex[2]))*-simplex[2] > 0) {
            std::cout << "AB";
            //direction = AB x (A0 x AB)
            direction = (simplex[1]-simplex[2]) ^ ((-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[2]));
            simplex = {simplex[1], simplex[2]};
        //Line to oldest point is closest feature
        } else if (((simplex[0]-simplex[2])^((simplex[0]-simplex[2])^(simplex[1]-simplex[2])))*-simplex[2] > 0) {
            std::cout << "AC";
            //direction = AC x (A0 x AC)
            direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[2]) ^ ((-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[2]));
            simplex = {simplex[0], simplex[2]};
        //Face is closest feature
        } else {
            //Origin is in direction AC x AB
            if (((simplex[1]-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[2])) * (-simplex[2]) < 0) {
                std::cout << "ACxAB";
                //direction = AC x AB
                direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[2]);
            //origin is in direction AB x AC (other side of the face)
            } else {
                std::cout << "ABxAC";
                //direction = AB x AC
                direction = (simplex[1]-simplex[2]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[2]);
                simplex = {simplex[1], simplex[0], simplex[2]};
            }
        }
        break;
    //If the simplex is a tetrahedron
    case 4:
        //Newest point is closest feature
        if ((simplex[0]-simplex[3])*(-simplex[3]) < 0 && (simplex[1]-simplex[3])*(-simplex[3]) < 0 &&
                (simplex[2]-simplex[3])*(-simplex[3]) < 0) {
            std::cout << "A";
            //direction = A0
            direction = -simplex[3];
            simplex = {simplex[3]};
        //Edge between newest and second-newest point is closest feature
        } else if ((((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ ((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]))) * (-simplex[3]) < 0) &&
                ((((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) < 0)) {
            std::cout << "AB";
            //direction = AB x (A0 x AB)
            direction = (simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ ((-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]));
            simplex = {simplex[2], simplex[3]};
        //Edge between newest and third-newest vertex is closest feature
        } else if ((((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ ((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3]))) * (-simplex[3]) < 0) &&
                ((((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) < 0)) {
            std::cout << "AC";
            //direction = AC x (A0 x AC)
            direction = (simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ ((-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3]));
            simplex = {simplex[1], simplex[3]};
        //Edge between newest and oldest point is closest feature
        } else if ((((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ ((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3]))) * (-simplex[3]) < 0) &&
                ((((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3])) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) < 0)) {
            std::cout << "AD";
            //direction = AD x (A0 x AD)
            direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ ((-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3]));
            simplex = {simplex[0], simplex[3]};
        //Face between the three newest points is closest feature
        } else if (((simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) > 0) {
            std::cout << "ABC";
            //direction = AC x AB (outer normal of face)
            direction = (simplex[1]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[2]-simplex[3]);
            simplex = {simplex[1], simplex[2], simplex[3]};
        //Face between newest, second-newest and oldest point is closest feature
        } else if (((simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) > 0) {
            std::cout << "ABD";
            //direction = AB x AD
            direction = (simplex[2]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[0]-simplex[3]);
            simplex = {simplex[2], simplex[0], simplex[3]};
        //Face between newest, second-oldest and oldest point is closest feature
        } else if (((simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3])) * (-simplex[3]) > 0) {
            std::cout << "ACD";
            //direction = AD x AC
            direction = (simplex[0]-simplex[3]) ^ (simplex[1]-simplex[3]);
            simplex = {simplex[0], simplex[1], simplex[3]};
        //Origin is encased by simplex
        } else {
            //Collision detected
            std::cout << "ABCD";
            return true;
        }
        break;
    default:
        direction = {1,1,1};
        simplex = {};
        break;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it's stuck in one of the 4ABC, 4ABD or 4 ACD cases.

Comment: @the_Seppi - See my updated answer for an additional fix to your output simplexes (included in the complete fixed function). I think the ordering of your output triangles was wrong.

Comment: @the_Seppi - Now i did a mistake on my own, fixed it again.

Comment: Now it's working most of the time. However, it sometimes still hangs in a loop of various triagle- and tetrahedron-cases (which aren't handled in any logical sequence, it just takes an infinite time to run the algorithm...)

Comment: There can be situations in which the GJK suffers from numerical inaccuracies or degenerated simplexes. Most implementations detect those situations and handle them separately; you have to analyze your concrete situation and see what really happens (it can help a lot to visualize the minkowski hull and the simplexes that are generated step-by-step)

Comment: How would you visualize the simplex?

Comment: The simplex is a set of points on the hull of the minkowski difference of the polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

```
case 2:
    //Point is closest feature
    if ((simplex[0]-simplex[1])*-simplex[1] < 0) {
        std::cout << "A";
        simplex = {simplex[1]};
        //direction = A0
        direction = -simplex[1];
    //Line is closest feature
```

Should you set `direction` before you set `simplex`? Otherwise you are trying to access the 2nd element of a length-1 vector.

Also, your function `gjkSupport()` as written accepts `std::vector` objects instead of `std::vector&` objects. This is likely to slow performance, as the vectors are getting copied-constructed every time you call the function.

Comment: Thank you for both of your suggestions. The command order you pointed out indeed was an error, but unfortunately it doesn't fix the code.